# setinterval in jquery ui not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a hard time replicating the functionality of http://jsfiddle.net/fmLAq/

```
progressbar.progressbar({
    value: false,
    change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
    },
    complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
    }
});

function progress() {
    var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

    progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );

    if ( val < 99 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
    }
}
```

IN

http://jsfiddle.net/x76ET/. I want to show the progressvalue inside the bar as in the above example.

Can anyone help me figure this out

Comment: Do you want [__this__](http://jsfiddle.net/x76ET/1/)?

Comment: @Satpal The OP wanted to show the increasing value 0,1,2+++++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = $('#my-progress');
var lab = $("#progress-label");
el.on('progressbarcreate', function (event, ui) {
    el.after('<p>Start value: ' + el.progressbar('value') + '</p>');
});

el.progressbar({
    change: function () {
        lab.text(el.progressbar("value"));
    },
    complete: function() {
        lab.text("Complete!");
    }
});

// animate progress
var count = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (count++ > 100) {
        // Stop repeating
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        el.progressbar('value', count);
    }
}, 100);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x76ET/7/)

Comment: thanks..In your example, how do I show the message 'Loading' and 'Complete' as in the original example? Also why is the progress bar looping and not stopping at 100. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's looping because that's how setInterval works -- it repeats until you call `clearInterval` to stop it. You coded it to go back to 0 after it reaches 100. Why didn't you program it to stop if that's what you wanted?

Comment: You can show the loading and complete messages just as in your first code. What's the problem?

Comment: Well I am not able to figure it out that's why I am here

Comment: You figured it out when you wrote the first code. There's no difference. Just add the 'complete:' function, just like in your first code.

Comment: And for the `Loading` message, that just comes from the original HTML. So add it to the HTML in the second fiddle.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to stop it when it reaches 100, and show Complete.